# Disabling a web service used to help resolve spelling errors in Chromium

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, chromium, spell-check

[Option in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOUKc.png)

I'm using Chromium, and have enabled this option some time ago. I no longer remember how I did this. I would like to disable this option now, but cannot find it in Settings. I'm using Windows 10. This is how this option looks like:
[image: shown in red circle]

Comment: Someone ***correct me please if I am wrong***.  This is NOT what a web service is.  Just because it is something the web browser does doesn't make it a web API.  A web service is a remote API that allows you to access code functions remotely.  It is possible that what you are talking about USES such a service but that isn't what you are saying.  Editing your title might help get better results.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Typically you're correct. However, with Chrome there is an option for 'Enhanced Spell Check' wherein your all text typed in the browser _is_ sent to the Google server.

Comment: @lost_admin .. :)  I stand corrected.  I would still argue that he isn't trying to "disable a web service" .. but that is nothing but stupid English semantics.  Thanks for the information.. I think we all like getting smarter.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I absolutely see where you’re coming from! Yes always learning new stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is in `Settings -> Advanced -> Languages -> Enhanced Spell Check` **OR** `Settings -> Sync and Google Services -> Enhanced Spell Check`

Hope this helps!

-L_A

Comment: Nice answer sir.